# C# compare a list of IDs to each ID in a list of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to compare list of ints to a list of objects. to see if one of the IDs match the a key in each object. If it does then return true, else false.

for example:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> () { 
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

List<someObjectType> objects = new List<someObjectType> () { 
  {1, "one"}, {6, "six"}, {45, "forty-five"} };

(x => x.objects.any(a => ints.contains(x.id)));
```

However I don't know how to compare a list of ints to only one property on an object, I only know how to compare whole arrays to each other.

Comment: Are you working against an anonymous type? You won't be able to access the properties without `dynamic` or reflection for runtime binding, or `var` for compile-time binding. In a `List<anon>`, `var` is not usable. Your use of an anonymous type here seems contrived.

Comment: Why are you using List<object> instead of a Dictionary, or at least a List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>?

Comment: You could consider a `Dictionary<int,string>`

Comment: I agree with @CallumBradbury. The `List<object>` should be `Dictionary<int,string>` or `List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`.

Comment: or at least a list of Tuple<int, string>...

Comment: I've updated the question - I'm working with known types

Comment: 'one' is not a valid string.  Additionally, your construction sequence isn't correct. {{1,"one"}} isn't valid for a List<someObjectType> that I am aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
  List<int> ints = new List<int> () { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  // For better performance when "ints" is long
  HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(ints);

  List<someObjectType> objects = new List<someObjectType> () { 
    {1, "one"}, {6, "six"}, {45, "forty-five"} };

  // if any is matched?
  boolean any = objects
    .Any(item => ids.Contains(item.id));

  // All that match
  var objectsThatMatch = objects
    .Where(item => ids.Contains(item.id));
```

Comment: with a little work this ended up being the solution
(p => p.object != null && p.object.Any(o => ids.Contains(o.id)));

Comment: This looks to me like it would not compile -- `'one'` is not a valid C# constant.

Comment: @Hogan: you're quite right it sould be "one", "six" etc. I've just copied the code from the question

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo-code is pretty much there (though with `Where` instead of `Any`)...

```
var objectsWithIds = objects.Where(o => ints.Contains(o.Id));
```

Which makes me suspect this isn't what you are after...

Another way is using `Intersect`, but you need to translate them both into an `IEnumerable<>` of the same type.

```
var intersectionOfIds = objects.Select(_ => _.Id).Intersect(ints);
```

But this only gets you a list of Ids that are in both lists, not the objects themselves, which you would then need to go and find again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `object`, you could use the keyword [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), but an even better solution would be to use some static type (if possible).

You can use `dynamic` like a dictionary, the added link will provide you with some great examples.

Comment: sorry - fixed. Object was just a placeholder for an actual object type.

Answer (score 0):

I was close

```
(x => x.objects.any(a => ints.contains(a.id)));
```